# How to add a certificate to a trusted store so that Fegin can access it?

Tags: ssl-certificate, spring-cloud-feign, truststore

Using the feign client, I try to access a resource in my Spring application, but I get the following error:

```
feign.RetryableException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target executing POST
```

I added the certificate to trusted certificates in ubuntu, but without result.

I think that I need to use keytool and add certificate in truststore, but I don't know how